# Best way to add line break for each specified character? (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, gridview, line-breaks

I'm having trouble getting line breaks to occur on a specific character on my asp.net site.  I have a gridview with user accounts that has an 'Entitlements' column/field, in which data is entered with pipes, such as the following:

'Admin|Trader|Support|Sales'

I know this is not the best data architecture, but it has to stay like this for the time being until we add an entitlements table in the database.

Now, what I want to display in the actual gridview is this:

Admin
Trader
Support
Sales

In other words I want to replace each pipe with a line break, or at least add a line break at each pipe, so that each entitlement is on a separate line.

Is there a way to do this in my CSS class?  I looked through different attributes such as white-space, text-overflow, and word-wrap, but so far I haven't found anything that will say "wrap text on any occurence of *this* character".  I suppose I can use jQuery to do this, but it seems like there should be a simpler solution.

If jQuery *is* the way to go, then an example would be appreciated, as I'm new to jQuery.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you want the values to appear in different rows on in same row?

Comment: I assume you should preprocess the string and replace pipes with line breaks. Something like http://jsfiddle.net/jQqyx/.

Comment: I want the values in a single row.  I think I've got this mostly figured out now, but the field also needs to be updateable, so I need a way to switch the line breaks back to pipes when updating.  I think this should be doable with the same method though.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it any number of ways.

In the database:

```
SELECT REPLACE(entitlements, '|', '<br/>')
```

In jQuery:

```
$('.entitlements').each(function(){
    var $obj = $(this);
    var txt = $obj.text();
    $obj.html(txt.replace(/|/g, '<br/>'))
});
```

In asp.net:

```
<%# FormatEntitlements(Eval("Entitlements"))%>

public static string FormatEntitlements(string entitlements)
{
    return (entitlements ?? "").Replace("|", "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I forgot to mention that this field is editable, so I need a way to switch the line breaks back to pipes again when the field is updated, but I think (hope) that should be fairly straight forward in the 'updating' event of the gridview.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution:

```
var orig = $('#menu').html();
$('#menu').html(orig.replace(/\|/g,'<br />'));​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BgM7A/)